# Weighted overlay output raster does not match the extent of my input rasters

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, weighted-overlay

[image: Weighted overlay output, on top of one of my input rasters]

I am having trouble understanding why the resulting extent of my raster produced by my weighted overlay doesn't not cover the extent of the inputs I used. All my inputs are in the same coordinate system and using the same datum.

The environment settings has my processing extent set to the grey input raster, as does the raster analysis cell size. All my other inputs have the same extent/outline as the grey raster shown in the image, so I am wondering why the weighted overlay output does not cover the entire area?

[image: This is the input raster I used]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the problem on my own. All I had to do was take all my input layers and project them into a projected coordinate system, from GCS_WGS_1984 into NAD_1983_2011_StatePlane_California_VI_FIPS_0406_Ft_US, then I deleted my old model, reset all my enviornment settings, and make a new model, and it worked just fine.